# UnsupportedOperationException javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName() is not supported

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-security

I am trying to access HttpServletRequest.getServerName() within a CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot

```
request.getServerName()
```

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {

public CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a, FilterInvocation fi) {
    super(a, fi);
}

public boolean isLocal() {
    return "localhost".equals(request.getServerName());
}
```

}

This expression root is being set in the FilterSecurityInterceptor

```
    @Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    final HttpSecurity http = getHttp();
    web.postBuildAction(() -> {
        FilterSecurityInterceptor fsi = http.getSharedObject(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
        fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(metadataSource);
        web.securityInterceptor(fsi);
    });
}
```

Then I have a database entry to set "*local and hasRole("ADMIN")*" which calls this expression.

It appears there is a Proxy wrapping the ServletRequest as a "DummyRequest" and all other methods are unsupported.

But when this gets executed, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName() is not supported
at org.springframework.security.web.UnsupportedOperationExceptionInvocationHandler.invoke(FilterInvocation.java:235) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getServerName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getServerName(ServletRequestWrapper.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
```

Comment: one question, from where is called the  isLocal() method? is it form an interceptor? could you share that part? and also `CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot` is a component? were is injected?

Answer (score 1):

We just found out our issue with that. Spring Boot forwards internal for the `/error` page (in our case 401) and uses a `DummyRequest` in that context. So we have to check for the class type as well

```java
  private fun forPort(port: Int): RequestMatcher {
        return RequestMatcher { request: HttpServletRequest ->
            // Spring Boot does intercept error messages and put it into a DummyRequest
            request.javaClass.name != "org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation\$DummyRequest" && port == request.localPort }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative

Create a simple bean that receives the request as parameter

```
@Component
public class WebChecker {
        public boolean isLocalHost(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
            System.out.println("Server name" + request.getServerName());
            return "localhost".equals(request.getServerName());
        }
}
```

Then in your security configuration you can invoke the isLocalHost method as an expression through the access configuration like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/stores").access("@webChecker.isLocalHost(authentication,request)")
```

There is more information in Spring Oficial Site [26.2.1 Referring to Beans in Web Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-beans)

Hope this alternative helps you.

Comment: This is an great alternative, but I get the same issue "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName() is not supported". Why is there a proxy wrapping this request?

Comment: ok, if you try to  use the the common built in expression that can help you?, for  example "hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.0/24')"

Comment: Daniel, sorry but I need a custom expression to check if the request is coming from a specific serverName as should be available in the servletRequest, but it has been proxied, and is not available :-(

Comment: ok, I'll check again, it is strange  I'm not  getting that error, but using the WebChecker alternative, I'll try to replicate the error and let you know.

Comment: Also note I am NOT using the antMatchers, I am using this as custom metadata